# Dynamically fill and update items in a combobox

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

I am working on a project for creating course schedule. I am working on Access. So, let say I have  created table with some courses. Now I want to use combo boxes which are bind with the table data. I have managed to do this. But my problem is for example. If I select one course in first combo box, I  want that in the second combo box that course to be disabled so that I cannot chose it. And so on for every combo box (Let say do this for six combo boxes)

I have this code. But the problem with my code is that whenever I chose something on the third combo box my data are erased from the combo box above.

```
 Private Sub cboMonday_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboTuesday.RowSource = "SELECT CourseName FROM" & _
                               " tblCourses "

    Me.cboWednesday.RowSource = "SELECT CourseName FROM" & _
                               " tblCourses "

    MsgBox ("After Monday=   ")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.cboMonday.ListCount - 1
        If i <> Me.cboMonday.Value - 1 Then
           Me.cboTuesday.AddItem (Me.cboMonday.ItemData(i))
        End If
    Next
    Me.cboTuesday = Me.cboTuesday.ItemData(0)

    For i = 0 To Me.cboMonday.ListCount - 1
        If i <> Me.cboMonday.Value - 1 Then
           Me.cboWednesday.AddItem (Me.cboMonday.ItemData(i))
        End If
    Next
    Me.cboWednesday = Me.cboWednesday.ItemData(1)

End Sub

Private Sub cboTuesday_AfterUpdate()
    Me.cboWednesday.RowSource = "SELECT CourseName FROM" & _
                               " tblCourses "


    Dim i As Integer

    MsgBox ("After Tuesday=   ")
    For i = 0 To Me.cboMonday.ListCount - 1
        If i <> Me.cboMonday.Value - 1 And i <> Me.cboTuesday.Value - 1 Then
           Me.cboWednesday.AddItem (Me.cboMonday.ItemData(i))
        End If
    Next
    Me.cboWednesday = Me.cboWednesday.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding/deleting items from Table/Query combobox is not good solution, the list will be refreshed when main form refreshed an in many other situations, including change of Row Source property, like in your example.

Better way is to create rowsource queries with references to other comboboxes. For instance, if in cboWednesday I don't want to include course, selected in cboMonday and cboTuesday, the Row Source property of cboWednesday will be `SELECT CourseName FROM tblCourses WHERE CourseName Not In ([Forms]![Form1]![cboMonday],[Forms]![Form1]![cboTuesday]);`. For other comboboxes you can add as many references to other comboboxes as you want. 
In AfterUpdate combobox events just refresh comboboxes, which depend on current one.

This should work if bound and display columns are the same, like in your example. If bound column is hidden, the data may disappear after requery. In this case you can leave full list of courses in all comboboxes, but in BeforUpdate event check if cource was already selected in other comboboxes and deny selection with warning.

Comment: how do I deny the selection with warning.

Comment: `BeforeUpdate` event has parameter `Cancel`. If you set it to `True`, selected value won't be accepted. Check if was selected wrong value, popup message, set `Cancel=true` and exit from sub